# i dont know whats wrong with my c++ code because there is no warning appear

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>              //header mysql
#include <sstream>              //merubah semua tipe data yang diinputkan user ke string
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
int main()
 {
string data, hadis, hadis1, hadis2;
const char *hadiss;
int itung = 0;
MYSQL* conn;                //for connection handler
MYSQL_ROW row;              //return data as array of strings
MYSQL_RES* res;             //hold the result set
int num_fields;             //to get the number of array
conn = mysql_init(0);       //initialaize connection handler. dont change!
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "192.168.43.205", "ibrahim", "hadis", "dbdb", 0, NULL, 0);
if(conn)
{
    int qstate = mysql_query(conn, "SELECT Isi_Indonesia FROM malik");
    if(!qstate)
    {
        res = mysql_store_result(conn);
        num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);
        while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
        {
            data = row[0];
            regex reg("[^\\w]+");
            data = regex_replace(data, reg, " ");
            //cout << data <<"\n\n";
            istringstream stm(data) ;
            while( stm >> hadis )                      // read white-space delimited tokens one by one
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
                {
                    hadiss = hadis.c_str();
                        cout << hadiss << endl;
                    if(hadiss != NULL)
                    {
                        hadis1 = hadiss;
                        string query1 = "SELECT kata FROM totalkata_malik2 WHERE kata='"+hadis1+"'";
                        mysql_query(conn, query1.c_str());
                        res = mysql_store_result(conn);
                        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
                        {
                            if (row[0] == NULL)
                            {
                                string query2 = "INSERT INTO totalkata_malik2(kata,total) VALUES ('"+hadis1+"',1)";
                                mysql_query(conn, query2.c_str());
                                itung++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string query3 = "UPDATE totalkata_malik2 SET total=total+1 where kata='"+hadis1+"'";
                                mysql_query(conn, query3.c_str());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout<< "\n\nJumlah kata = "<<itung++<<"\n\n";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

this is my c++ code and i got no warning when i was running this program but the result is not like what i want, the result that i hope look like this:

[image: this is the result that i hope in mysql database]

but my result did not insert or update anything in mysql databse, therefore mysql database was empty.
but if i deleted "select kata query till row part " my insert into query code could insert the word to "kata field" at database but the code didnt update the "total field" properly

Comment: `string query3 = "UPDATE totalkata_malik2 SET total=total+1 where kata='"+hadis1+"'";` that's dangerous and you shouldn't do it. Don't build the queries yourself. Use prepared statements. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: Is there a reason you use the C API in your C++ code? MySQL has a C++ API https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/

Comment: [OT]: sub-functions might help...

Comment: Did you verify in the debugger that the code that does the `INSERT` is reached? If so did you check how `query2` in that case looks like, and if it is valid, by e.g. directly executing it in pypMyAdmin? Furthermore, you don't do any error checking `mysql_query` has a return value that tells you if the query was successful or failed.